# Bit.dev (Bit Harmony): `bit tag` command fails to complete

Tags: bit.dev

I was exporting my component to Bit.dev, when I got stuck at the `bit tag --message` command, with the error message: `Failed task 1: "teambit.pkg/pkg:PackComponents" of env "teambit.harmony/node"`

I have already ran the previous commands: `bit link --rewire`, `bit compile` and `bit build --all` prior. I would also like to mention that I have *circular dependencies* errors which I workaround with the `--ignore-issues \"CircularDependencies\"` flag.

Have anyone faced this issue before, and managed to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have circular dependencies, when tagging a component Bit cannot create a package.json file for it. This is a necessary step to bundle the component. Since you have circular dependencies, this step gets stuck and errors.

Solve your circular dependencies -avoid importing component A to component B and viceversa- and you should be fine.